# How to manipulate y-axis text labels in R varImpPlot?

Tags: r

The following sample resembles my dataset:

```
require(randomForest)

alpha = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
bravo = c(2,3,4,5,6,7)
charlie = c(2,6,5,3,5,6)
mydata = data.frame(alpha,bravo,charlie)

myrf = randomForest(alpha~bravo+charlie, data = mydata, importance = TRUE)

varImpPlot(myrf, type = 2)
```

I cannot seem to control the placement of the y-axis labels in `varImpPlot`.  I have tried altering the plot parameters (e.g. mar, oma), with no success.  I need the y-axis labels shifted to the left in order to produce a PDF with proper label placement.

**How can I shift the y-axis labels to the left?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to use `adj` parameter but it produces a bug. As varImpPlot , use `dotchart` behind, Here a version using lattice `dotplot`. Then you can customize you axs using `scales` parameters.

```
imp <- importance(myref, class = NULL, scale = TRUE, type = 2)
dotplot(imp, scales=list(y =list(cex=2,
                                       at = c(1,2),
                                       col='red',
                                       rot =20,
                                       axs='i') ,
                               x =list(cex=2,col='blue')) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the data needed to construct the plot out of myref and construct a plot with ggplot. By doing so you have more freedom in tweaking the plot. Here are some examples

```
library(ggplot2)

str(myrf)
str(myrf$importance)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(rownames(myrf$importance),round(myrf$importance[,"IncNodePurity"],1)))
colnames(data) <- c("Parameters","IncNodePurity")
data$IncNodePurity <- as.numeric(as.character(data$IncNodePurity))
```

Standard plot:

```
(p <- ggplot(data) + geom_point(aes(IncNodePurity,Parameters)))
```

Rotate y-axis labels:

```
(p1 <- p+ theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)))
```

Some more tweaking (also first plot shown here):

```
(p2 <- p1 +  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(3,7),breaks=3:7) + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()))
```

Plot that looks like the varImpPlot (second plot shown here) :

```
(p3 <- p2+ theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = 'gray', linetype = 'dashed'),
panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='black')))
```

Saving to pdf is easy with ggplot:

```
ggsave("randomforestplot.pdf",p2)
```

or

```
ggsave("randomforestplot.png",p2)

p2
```

[image]

```
p3
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did I understood correctly, that you want to get texts `charlie` and `bravo` more left of the boundary of the plot? If so, here's one hack to archive this, based on the modification of the `rownames` used in plotting:

```
myrf = randomForest(alpha~bravo+charlie, data = mydata, importance = TRUE)
#add white spaces at the end of the rownames
rownames(myrf$importance)<-paste(rownames(myrf$importance), "   ") 
varImpPlot(myrf, type = 2)
```

The adj parameter in `dotchart` is fixed as 0 (align to right), so that cannot be changed without modifying the code of `dotchart`:

```
mtext(labs, side = 2, line = loffset, at = y, **adj = 0**, col = color, 
    las = 2, cex = cex, ...)
```

(from `dotchart`)

**EDIT**:
You can make another type of hack also. Take the code of `dotchart`, change the above line to

```
 mtext(labs, side = 2, line = loffset, at = y, adj = adjust_ylab, col = color, 
        las = 2, cex = cex, ...)
```

Then add argument `adjust_ylab` to the argument list, and rename the function as for example `dotchartHack`. Now copy the code of `varImpPlot`, find the line which calls `dotchart`, change the function name to `dotchartHack` and add the argument `adjust_ylab=adjust_ylab` to function call, rename the function to `varImpPlotHack` and add `adjust_ylab` to this functions argument list. Now you can change the alignment of the `charlie` and `bravo` by changing the parameter `adjust_ylab`:

```
 myrf = randomForest(alpha~bravo+charlie, data = mydata, importance = TRUE) 
 varImpPlotHack(myrf, type = 2,adjust_ylab=0.5)
```

From `?par`:

> The value of adj determines the way in which text strings are
>   justified in text, mtext and title. A value of 0 produces
>   left-justified text, 0.5 (the default) centered text and
>   right-justified text. (Any value in [0, 1] is allowed, and on most
>   devices values outside that interval will also work.)